# Downloading external libraries with cmake: how let users choose?

Tags: cmake

I use CMake to download external libraries called into my code (with the External_project_add command). However, I would like to let users choose if they want to let CMake download these libraries or if they want to install them manually and provide paths to them. Furthermore, I would like to let users make different choices for each libraries. For example, they could:

- download all external libraries
- download nothing
- download one specific library but not another.

Is it possible to do this with CMake?

Thank you very much!

Comment: ***Is it possible to do this with CMake?*** Yes. Use option() to control what gets built via  External_project_add instead of what gets found using cmake find modules.

Comment: @drescherjm: Would you mind converting your comment to an answer which then can be accepted by Aleph? Otherwise this question looks like unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option() to control what gets built via External_project_add instead of what gets found using CMake find modules. For example:

```
option( USE_SYSTEM_GDCM "Build using the installed system GDCM" OFF)

if (USE_SYSTEM_GDCM) 
  find_package(GDCM REQUIRED)
  include(${GDCM_USE_FILE})
else (USE_SYSTEM_GDCM)
   External_project_add( ... )
endif(USE_SYSTEM_GDCM)
```